# OTRS with LDAP authentication not working

Tags: authentication, ldap, debian, otrs

I'm running OTRS 5s on my server and need to configure LDAP authentization in it.

currently i have this code:

```
$Self->{'AuthModule'} = 'Kernel::System::Auth::LDAP';
$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::Host'} = '127.0.0.1';
$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::BaseDN'} = 'dc=domain,dc=com';
$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::UID'} = 'uid';
$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::SearchUserDN'} = 'cn=tester,cn=adminuser,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com';
$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::SearchUserPw'} = 'tester';
```

last two lines should be ok but I'm getting this error on site

```
Panic, user authenticated but no user data can be found in OTRS DB!! Perhaps the user is invalid.
```

I also tried version which I found here and on other sites, but thats not working at all with following code:

```
$Self->{'AuthModule'} = 'Kernel::System::Auth::LDAP';
$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::Host'} = '127.0.0.1';
$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::BaseDN'} = 'dc=domain,dc=com';
$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::UID'} = 'sAMAccountName';
$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::GroupDN'} = 'cn=adminuser,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com';
$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::AccessAttr'} = 'member';
$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::UserAttr'} = 'DN';
$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::SearchUserDN'} = 'cn=tester,cn=adminuser,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com';
$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::SearchUserPw'} = 'tester';
```

but it results in wrong password or username and apache error.log calling

```
ERROR: OTRS-CGI-45 Perl: 5.20.2 OS: linux Time: Mon Dec  5 18:19:41 2016
Message: No UserID found for 'tester'!
```

both codes have

```
$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::Params'} = {
    port => 389,
    timeout => 120,
    async => 0,
    version => 3,
};
```

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User (agents) need to exists in the database before you can use LDAP authentication for them. Add them manually or configure the AuthSyncModule module.

Comment: i tried to configure AuthSyncModule module, but I'm getting same result

Comment: after few tries, it resulted into `Message: Can't create user 'tester' (cn=tester,cn=adminuser,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com) in RDBMS!`

Comment: The user need these attributes in the Active Directory:

Comment: - givenName, sn, mail

Answer (score 0):

Use the below parameters after the `$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::Params'}` section:

```
$Self->{'AuthSyncModule::LDAP::UserSyncMap'} = {
UserFirstname => 'givenName',
UserLastname  => 'sn',
UserEmail     => 'mail',
};
```